# How do i get return value of action running in a thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to make a function to run stuff in a throw-away thread... aka keep executing stuff without waiting for the function in the line before it to excute.

So i made a little function here...

```
public static object Do(System.Action Method)
{
      object ret;
      System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() => 
      {ret = Method(); });
      t.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
      t.Start();
      return ret;
}
```

Looks simple... there is only one problem... i get the following errors

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'
>
> Use of unassigned local variable 'ret'

I don't care about the second because it will fix itself if i just fix the first... but i don't seem to find a solution for the first...

In short:
All i want is to get the return value of the function chosen aka...

I want the following code to work:

```
string TEST = Do(() => Console.ReadKey()).ToString();
```

But the method itself is broken.

Comment: If you are doing `System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA` you are required to have a "Message pump" and you are not allowed to block the thread for long periods of time. I highly suspect you are not doing this. Why not just use `Task.Run` instead of your custom `Do` method, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Don't use threads unless you really need to, there is a much better abstraction such as the *TPL* library and the `Task<T>` which should do the job more easily

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  You say you want a result from the method, but you also want to execute stuff without waiting for the result.  That can't happen.  That's like saying you want to eat your pizza while it's still in the oven.

Comment: And not only that, but you want the result to be the result of calling an `Action` - which has a `void` return type...

Comment: Basically just forget you ever saw about "Threads"  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Action` delegate does not return a value.

Use `Func<object>` to return `object` from a passed function.

Also in this case the variable will be most likely returned before the function completes.

I recommend using `async/await` combination instead. In order for your construction to work you would have do something like this:

```
public static async Task<object> Do(Func<object> Method)
{
    object ret = null;

    await Task.Run(
    () =>
    {
        ret = Method();
    });

    return ret;
}
```

Which boils down to:

```
public static async Task<object> Do(Func<object> Method)
{
    return Task.Run(Method);
}
```

Example code:

```
class Program
{
    static AutoResetEvent MyThreadCompletedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    static async void MyThread()
    {
        Console.WriteLine((await MyClass<ConsoleKeyInfo>.Do(Console.ReadKey)).ToString());
        MyThreadCompletedEvent.Set();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => MyThread());

        // Do stuff

        // Ensure to wait for MyThread to complete
        MyThreadCompletedEvent.WaitOne();
    }
}

public static class MyClass<T>
{
    public static async Task<object> Do(Func<T> Method)
    {
        return await Task.Run(Method);
    }
}
```

Instead of creating new thread you could do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass<ConsoleKeyInfo>.Do(Console.ReadKey));
    }
}

public static class MyClass<T>
{
    public static object Do(Func<T> Method)
    {
        return Method();
    }
}
```

Comment: So while the first part of your answer is true (`Action` vs `Func`), there is no advantage to your `Do` method.  It is the same as `await Method()`, with some extra overhead.

Comment: At this point, I'm not sure you need `ret` at all or even `async` - why not just return `Task.Run(Method())`? Unless you really want `Method` itself (which *provides* the task) to be called on a different thread...

Comment: But eh i can't use stuff like"Console.writeline()"

Comment: @Emily I have included example code although it seems to be super boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

From your title:

> How do i get return value of action running in a thread in C#?

You can't.  If the thread is still *running*, the "return value" has not yet been computed.  It is not available to return, even if you used the correct `Func<T>` instead of `Action<T>`.

In other words, the laws of physics in our universe as we currently know them do not allow for retrieving information from the future.

> I want the following code to work:
>
> ```
> string TEST = Do(() => Console.ReadKey()).ToString();
> ```

Assuming you meant `TEST` to have the value of the pressed key, then you have to wait for the key to be pressed.  The same thing would be obtained with:

```
string TEST = Console.ReadKey().ToString();
```

(though you probably would want to use the `.KeyChar` property...)

Comment: Awaiting a `Task<T>` is how you *retrieve information from the future*; in many languages what C# calls "task" is called "future", to emphasize that.

Comment: @EricLippert The task still has to complete before the result is available.  The OP seemed to want to continue with the next statement before the operation had completed *and* somehow still have the result that would come only from finishing the task.